# Spinnaker on Kubernetes, who discover the kubernetes service named spkr-orca via Environment variables or DNS

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I looked into Spinnaker on Kubernetes in https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/blob/master/experimental/kubernetes, and I have a question, the kubernetes service named spkr-orca is created using "kubectl create -f svcs/spkr-orca.yaml", and I know we could discover the kubernetes service named spkr-orca via Environment variables or DNS, but I don't find who discover the kubernetes service named spkr-orca via Environment variables or DNS in /experimental/kubernetes, Is there anyone could tell me which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovery is done using DNS, and the endpoint the Orca service is bound to is configured [here](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/blob/master/experimental/kubernetes/config/spinnaker-local.yml#L100). This configuration is loaded into a Kubernetes secret, and then distributed to all the Spinnaker services as a mounted volume.

Comment: Thanks very much, I got it.